# How do I resize images to fit perfectly inside their containers while using CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm new to programming and have struggled with sizing images for a few weeks. When adding images from my computer they all overflow their containers unless I set a max-width. After setting max-width there is a lot of unwanted whitespace underneath each image.

What is the best way to make the images fit perfectly into their containers while also making it responsive? I am not confident that all of the width and height properties I have set are necessary.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
}

.main__content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 20%);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: "mc1 mc1 mc1 mc2 mc2"
                             "mc1 mc1 mc1 mc2 mc2"
                             "mc3 mc3 mc4 mc4 mc4"
                             "mc3 mc3 mc4 mc4 mc4"
                             "mc3 mc3 mc5 mc5 mc5"
                             "mc3 mc3 mc5 mc5 mc5"
                             "mc3 mc3 mc5 mc5 mc5";  
  height: 100%;
}

.main__content div {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.main__image-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.main__image-container img {
  width: 100%;
}

#main__content__cell-1 {
  grid-area: mc1;
}

#main__content__cell-2 {
  grid-area: mc2;
}

#main__content__cell-3 {
  grid-area: mc3;
}

#main__content__cell-4 {
  grid-area: mc4;
}

#main__content__cell-5 {
  grid-area: mc5;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <section class="main__content">
    <div class="main__image-container" id="main__content__cell-1">
      <img src="images/teepees.JPG" alt="coyotee buttes teepees">
    </div>
    <div class="main__image-container" id="main__content__cell-2">
      <img src="images/great_gallery.jpg" alt="great gallery">
    </div>
    <div class="main__image-container" id="main__content__cell-3">
      <img src="images/lake_powell.JPG" alt="lake powell">
    </div>
    <div class="main__image-container" id="main__content__cell-4">
      <img src="images/coyotee_gulch_campsite.jpg" alt="campsite">
    </div>
    <div class="main__image-container" id="main__content__cell-5">
      <img src="images/second_wave.JPG" alt="second wave">
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Thanks for helping me get over this hurdle :)

Answer (score 1):

Add following styles to your images to make them responsive:

```
.responsive-image {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For handling images perfectly, add the styling below:

```css
img{
  max-width: 100%; height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make an image responsive and also fill full width of its parent container you can give it the following rules:

```
.image{
    width:100%; /* this will make the image fill 100% width */
    height:auto; /* so that its height gets filled automatically acc to its width */
}
```

Note: if your image container is of fixed height and the image **width/height** proportions are not in same ratio as of containers **width/height** then either the image will leave white space below it or its height will overflow the container depending upon the proportions.